# How to redirect links inside iframe when users clicks "open in a new tab"?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web

I'm working on a web app that let the user use a bunch of services(spark etc.).
When the users choose to start a service, let's say Spark, the app will open a new tab in which there will be my page(service.html) that contains some info about the user and after that the iframe, like this:

```
 <table width="100%" style="padding: 0px;">
            <tr>
                <td align="right" style="padding: 0px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-wifi" style="color:gray;"> {{ some stuff}}</i>
                </td>
            </tr>
  </table>
  <iframe id="serviceIframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://localhost:{{port}}/{{page}}" target="_self"/>
```

Everything works fine, but my problem is that if the user click "open in a new tab" on any of the links within the iframe it will go to http://localhost:{{port}}/{{page}}, not to service html, and the content that I want to show alongside the service will be lost.

What can I do so that when a users click "open in a new tab" on a link inside the iframe it will redirect to my service.html page, not to http://localhost:{{port}}/{{page}}?

Thanks and sorry if I'm not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<a href="..." target="_top">My Link</a>` in frame links

Comment: I think the cross domain policy stops me from modifying the content of the iframe. Is there any other solution?

Comment: You cant modify the content of the iframe with javascript right. There is no way if you cant change  iframe resource code directly

Comment: Thank you for your response!